# When i attempted to record Web(HTTP/HTML) scripts in hp VUGEN it records invalid script?

Tags: loadrunner

when i attempted to record wed(HTTP/HTML) scripts in hp VUGEN for our wedsite,After recording it gives some invalid scripts like

Action()
{

```
web_custom_request("ocsp.godaddy.com", 
    "URL=http://ocsp.godaddy.com/", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/ocsp-response", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "EncType=application/ocsp-request", 
    "BodyBinary=0h0f0D0B0@0\t\\x06\\x05+\\x0E\\x03\\x02\\x1A\\x05\\x00\\x04\\x14p)\"vS\\x7F\\x1A\\xBC\\x8F\\xD5<\\x94\\x84\\xE9\\x14\\xCBv*\\x05*\\x04\\x14\\xFD\\xACa2\\x93lE\\xD6\\xE2\\xEE\\x85_\\x9A\\xBA\\xE7v\\x99h\\xCC\\xE7\\x02\\x07N\\xAA\\xCF\\xBC\\xAD\\xD7]\\xA2\\x1E0\\x1C0\\x1A\\x06\t+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x070\\x01\\x04\\x04\r0\\x0B\\x06\t+\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x05\\x070\\x01\\x01", 
    LAST);

return 0;
```

}

i used IE9 browser and loadrunner11.51

Comment: Do you have a question? Why do you deem that call "invalid" ?

Answer (score 0):

1. How do you know that the request is not valid?
2. Do you work for GoDaddy or have permission from those who own, manage or control the servers you are developing against to test their servers?  (see license agreement for LoadRunner)